# Best practice for Azure Integration CICD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

We have a bunch of logic apps, azure functions, service buses etc which caters to multiple integration use cases. All the resources are currently in a dev resource group and we are looking to release it to a test and eventually a prod resource group using CICD.

Questions

- we have all the resources including logic app in the as ARM templates, each time something in the work flow changes as part of bug fix or for a new release , does the whole logic app needs to be deployed or can just the work flow can be deployed ?
- if there were no changes done to the logic app or any other resource, does deploying its ARM template again cause any side effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your questions will change depending on the deployment mode you're going to be using, as well as the structure in which your resources are defined in your ARM-templates.

When deploying your resources to an Azure resource group, you'll have to set the deployment mode:

- Complete: replace everything inside the targeted RG
- Incremental: only apply changes to the resources inside the targeted RG, which are part of your deployment package.

*See full documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes)*

Depending on how you've structured your ARM templates (all resources in a single ARM template, 1 ARM template per resource, ...) you will be able to define how much of your Azure resources will be targeted by a single deployment pipeline.

Now, to answer your questions:

- Q1: Make sure to have a well-defined structure in your ARM templates.
  For example, create an *infrastructure*-ARM template + CI/CD-pipelines which will only handle the creation/configuration of the base components, e.g. storage account, service bus,...
  Next to that, create a domain/interface-specific template + pipeline which only handles those Logic Apps, etc. required by a single interface.
  This way, if you modify/fix a Logic App that is part of a specific interface, only this specific interface will get redeployed.
- Q2: Even when using the incremental deployment mode, all settings will be reapplied -> make sure your deployment procedure can handle (re)storing state if required.